# Using WUAPI to quietly install updates in C#

Tags: c#, windows, windows-update

I'm trying to create a program that will handle updates silently. I am using the wuapilib.dll, which comes with a number of classes (c#). My first revision of the program was as follows (ignore typo problems - its on another computer without internet access so i'm typing it by hand):

```
IUpdateSession mySess = new UpdateSession();
IUpdateSearcher mySear = mySess.CreateUpdateSearcher();
ISearchResult myRes = mySear.Search("Type='Software'");
IUpdateDownloader myDown = mySess.CreateUpdateDownloader();
IUpdateInstaller myInst = mySess.CreateUpdateInstaller();

myDown.Updates = myRes.Updates;
myDown.Download();
myInst.Updates = myRes.Updates;
myInst.Install();
```

Ignore the case where an update is already downloaded or installed, I'm omitting the logic above. My problem is that IUpdateInstaller doesn't allow you to force a quiet install - a number of updates require that a user click a confirmation box. The IUpdateInstaller2 class does (I got that from the second post down [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa387102%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)), but for the life of me I can't find a way to get an IUpdateInstaller2 object. Nothing seems to return one, and Microsoft's documentation doesn't contain any example code. Extensive googling returned nothing of use.

I think I'm really close - the functionality is there, I just can't quite access it.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Have you tried using IUnknown::QueryInterface to see if the object returned from CreateUpdateInstaller offers the IUpdateInstaller2 interface as well as the IUpdateInstaller interface?

Answer (score 1):

I checked that (or rather, I think i did - wasn't too clear on getting it to work), and it looks like the CreateUpdateInstaller only returns an IUpdateInstaller, nothing else.

However, I found code (on a chinese website, interestingly enough) that just directly cast the IUpdateInstaller to an IUpdateInstalelr2, which has solved my problems.

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

I have posted in another Question my app to, search, download and then install Windows updates.

See: [C# and WUAPI: BeginDownload function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8432767/c-sharp-and-wuapi-begindownload-function/15104521#15104521)

you can easily change the:

```
static class Program
{
/// <summary>
/// The main entry point for the application.
/// </summary>
[STAThread]
static void Main()
{
Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
Application.EnableVisualStyles();

Thread thread = new Thread(() =>
{
Form1 form1 = new Form1();
form1.Visible = false;
form1.ShowInTaskbar = false;
Application.Run(form1);
});

thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
thread.Start();
}
}
```

then handle

```
Application.Close();
```

after the events have done their thing. For example, if no Updates have been found, then close the app. I use the async properties of the interfaces so it can do what it needs to async.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I also searched a long time for it.
You just need to cast it

```
IUpdateInstaller2 installer = new UpdateInstaller();
```

According to Microsoft documentation there are also version 3 and 4 available. But this must be an error. The functions of version 3 are available also in IUpdateInstaller2 and the functions from version 4 I never found somewhere.