# C# WUApiLib - Download and Install Asynchronously

Tags: c#, winapi, asynchronous, visual-studio-2013, windows-update

I am programming using the WUApiLib library from Microsoft. I have written a simple application that searches for all software updates that are not installed and then downloads and installs them. This part is working perfectly (I used the code found here to help: http://www.nullskull.com/a/1592/install-windows-updates-using-c--wuapi.aspx).

However, I want to make use of the BeginDownload, EndDownload, BeginInstall, EndInstall functionality of the library so that it can report progress back to the interface. The functions in that article are synchronous and the functions I mention are asynchronous.

I am using the first answer on this page as a template:
[C# and WUAPI: BeginDownload function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8432767/c-sharp-and-wuapi-begindownload-function)

However, my Invoke() function is never getting called and I can't figure out why.

```
iUpdateDownloader_onProgressChanged progress = new iUpdateDownloader_onProgressChanged(this);
IDownloadJob downloadJob = downloader.BeginDownload(progress, new iUpdateDownloader_onCompleted(this), new iUpdateDownloader_state(this));

public class iUpdateDownloader_onProgressChanged : IDownloadProgressChangedCallback
{
    private frmMain form1;

    public iUpdateDownloader_onProgressChanged(frmMain mainForm)
    {
        this.form1 = mainForm;
    }

    // Implementation of IDownloadProgressChangedCallback interface...
    public void Invoke(IDownloadJob downloadJob, IDownloadProgressChangedCallbackArgs e)
    {

        decimal bDownloaded = ((e.Progress.TotalBytesDownloaded / 1024) / 1024);
        decimal bToDownloaded = ((e.Progress.TotalBytesToDownload / 1024) / 1024);
        bDownloaded = decimal.Round(bDownloaded, 2);
        bToDownloaded = decimal.Round(bToDownloaded, 2);

        form1.setDownloadProgressText("Downloading Update: "
         + e.Progress.CurrentUpdateIndex
         + "/"
         + downloadJob.Updates.Count
         + " - "
         + bDownloaded + "Mb"
         + " / "
         + bToDownloaded + "Mb");
    }
}
```

I can put a breakpoint on the first line in the Invoke function and it never reaches there.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

First thing I notice that's wrong: the call to form1.setDownloadProgressText is a call to the UI made from a different, asynchronous thread. You'll want to wrap that in a this.Invoke (if WinForms) or Dispatcher.Invoke (if WPF) to marshall the UI manipulation to the UI thread.

Also, the "this" variable is not available in the list of member variable declarations that occur before the constructor function, so

```
    iUpdateDownloader_onProgressChanged progress = new iUpdateDownloader_onProgressChanged(this);
    IDownloadJob downloadJob = downloader.BeginDownload(progress, new       
    iUpdateDownloader_onCompleted(this), new iUpdateDownloader_state(this));
```

isn't going to work unless it's wrapped in a constructor or form load event handler, which isn't pictured here.

MY GUESS IS THAT YOUR onState OBJECT IS GETTING INVOKED BEFORE THE ONE SHOWN HERE, AND IT IS ATTEMPTING TO MANIPULATE THE FORM FROM A THREAD OTHER THAN THE UI ONE, AND THIS BLOW-UP IS PREVENTING THE OTHER OBJECTS (INCLUDING THE ONE DEPICTED HERE) FROM EVER BEING INVOKED.

Comment: So instead of passing this, what would you pass?

Comment: You would pass "this", but you would do it inside a function such as at the end of your Form load event handler, when your UI pieces (which are referred to in your interface implementations) have been added to the window (InitializeComponent does that). The big thing, though, is marshalling the UI manipulation functions to the UI thread. Again, I think the onState implementation object may be causing an error by failing to do this, and the error stops everything.

Comment: If you need more information, don't hesitate to ask and I will try to further clarify.

Comment: You'll have to forgive me but I am usually a PHP programmer and not C# so a lot of this is going a bit over my head. I think I'm understanding you correctly when you're saying I should declare the iDownloadJob in the form Load function instead of where I have it and make it a member of the Form?